# suggestion on jquery vertical navigation menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a vertical navigation bar for my site... unfortunately not achieving what I want so hope I get some solution.

the vertical menu has list of categories ... followed by subcategories to each categories are appended using the following jquery
here is the code.

```
<div id="nav_menu">
<div id="menu_box">
<ul id="menu_ul">
<li ><a href="#" id="1" >Category1</a></li>
<li ><a href="#" id="1" >Category1</a></li>
<li ><a href="#" id="1" >Category1</a></li>
etc....
</ul>
</div>

<div id="menu_slider">
<ul id="submenu_ul">
</div>
</div>
```

here the submenu of each category is as follows...

```
<li id="1" href="#">category1
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">subcate1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">subcate2</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">subcate3</a></li>
   .
   .
   .
  etc    
  </ul>
</li>
```

jquery code is ...like this
//navigation menu on document ready

```
        $(".category").live('mouseover',function(event){
        $("#menu_slider").show();
        var D=$(this).html();
        var id=$(this).attr('id');

        var V=$("#hide"+id).html();
        $("#submenu_ul").html(V);
        $("#menu_slider h3").html(D);   
});
    //Document Click
    $(document).mouseup(function()
    {
     //$("#menu_slider").hide();

    });

    //Mouse click on sub menu
    $("#menu_slider").mouseup(function()
    {
    return false
    });

    //Mouse click on my account link
    $("#menu_box").mouseup(function()
    {
    return false
    });
```

it's working fine here, when I change the layout ...like this as per my layout requirement

```
<div class="container nav_menu">
<div class="sidebar menu_box">
<ul class="menu_ul">
</ul>
</div>
</div> 

<div id="menu_slider">
<ul id="submenu_ul">
</div>
</div>
```

the jquery functionality not working it's not appending the html content in to the mennu_slider submenu_ul...I changed them to class selectors in jquery...one problem

the second one is ..I want the menu to be like this, please see the image and do suggest me how to achieve this. This kind of menus can be seen on all shopping sites, so I am trying make it work...please finds the images attached!

please see the attachments.
image 1 is on home page it should shown all categories by default but on other pages should be closed and should work on hover effect as shown in pic.

image2 what I achieved so far.

[How I want the navigation menu](http://kubadesigns.in/img2.gif)

[what I made till now](http://kubadesigns.in/image3.jpg)

Comment: Those links aren't publicly accessible.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert: please do check now, i attached images again...

Comment: Anyone to help me out with this ....any ideas!